# If / then to set an Id - Invalid id

Tags: lookup, if

The below code is an attempt to push some child objects my code creates into a master opportunity.
Not all Opportunities will be children, hence I want to do a check.
TargetOpid is the variable I want to define with the if/then. If this Opportunity has a master_opportunity__c, then the TargetOpid should be that Master's id. If not, then the targetopId should be the Opportunity initiating the trigger, Opp.id. The error message is "Invalid id" when I use on a child opportunity that has a Master populated.

```
String TargetOpid ;
               
        
        if (opp.Master_Opportunity__c != '' )
            
    {
        system.debug('Master Op != NULL');
        TargetOpid = opp.Master_Opportunity__c;}
        else{
    TargetOpid = opp.id; 
        }
```

Comment: So, what part of this isn't working? Please edit your question with more information about what's actually not working, and which part of it you're stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text field values, when retrieved from the database (e.g. at the start of a trigger), will always be null or a non-empty string. In other words, your comparison should be:

```
if(opp.Master_Opportunity__c != null)
```

Note that `null != ''`. They are two different things. `null` is an unknown value, while `''` is a known value that is a string containing zero characters.

Comment: This worked. This make sense but the error wasn't clear to me.